# Dropdown not able to implement in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Route, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import Home from "./Home";
import Shop from "./Shop";
import About from "./About";

import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import Banner from "./components/Banner";



class Main extends Component {

  state = {
    topCategory: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:3030/topCategory')
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data.express.catalogGroupView);
        this.setState({
          topCategory: res.data.express.catalogGroupView
        })
      })
  }

  render() {

    const { topCategory } = this.state;
    const navList = topCategory.map(navList => {

      return (

          <li><button className="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">{navList.name}</button></li>

        )

    })

    return (
      <div>

      <ul className="header">{navList}</ul>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
      <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
      <p>Cras facilisis urna ornare ex volutpat, et
         convallis erat elementum. Ut aliquam, ipsum vitae
         gravida suscipit, metus dui bibendum est, eget rhoncus nibh
         metus nec massa. Maecenas hendrerit laoreet augue
         nec molestie. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis
        dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>
      <Banner />
      <Footer />
      </div>

    )

  }


}

export default Main;
```

I'm new to react and I have tried designing a home page. The navigation is populating from an external API endpoint. But when I click on the particular links, like Apparel, Electronics etc, a dropdown should appear which I'm unable to implement. Can someone please help me on this. I know in normal HTML, this can be implemented very easily. But in react, I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import Bootstrap. Make sure Bootstrap dependencies (popper & jquery) are included too...

**package.json**

```
...  
"dependencies": {
    "react": "16.4.2",
    "react-dom": "16.4.2",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.3"
},
...
```

**react app**

```
        import React from "react";
        import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

        /* this imports the Bootstrap js */
        import bootstrap from "bootstrap";
        /* this imports the Bootstrap css */
        import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
        ...
```

Working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/r774l05qo4

Answer (score -1):

> It won't work because you didn't import jquery to work with bootstrap and this element requires it.
>
> I suggest you use some react boostrap alternatives, like the following:

[react-bootstrap dropdown](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/dropdowns/)

[reactstrap dropdown](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/dropdowns/)